# Is there any maximum limit to show number of bottom tabbar items in iOS?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

In my iOS app I want to display more than 8 items in my bottom bar like tab bar items.

For that I have used UICollectionView like tab bar at the bottom.
But one of my friends told me that Apple will reject the app if the bottom bar has more than 5 items. Is that true?

Or does that restriction only apply to UITabBar?

Please confirm. I am using UICollectionView instead of UITabBar.

Comment: why this question have `appstore` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

It is true. The human interface guidelines say that for a bottom bar there should be around 3 to 5 items.

Comment: But here I am using UICollectionView.

Comment: RSP if you are using collection view, i think there is no limit

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it, but for his purpose you need to make a custom tab bar, you can't use tab bar controller, 
Place a UIView on top of a controller where you see view controller and exit etc. and place a view inside it and place Image view and buttons and set constraints.